# How to create a website from already inter-linked html files

Tags: webserver, website, web, hosting

I have a collection of html files (and related files in folders) on PC which are linked to each other and I want to upload them to a web server instead of recreating the web pages online, but I don't know if this is possible and which servers support this?

Comment: please add more details to your questions, it's very vague and unclear

Answer (score 0):

Call GoDaddy.com.  They can do that.  I have 3 websites, one of which was a series of html pages.  I have a software program for websites, so I could link them myself and not pay GoDaddy to do that part of it.  Just tell them you want them to host it.  Of course you need to by a URL, but those are cheap.  Their tech support is very good and free. (I do not work for GoDaddy)

Comment: you are assuming the person asking question is using go daddy. I see no mention of it. also it's very badly written question. So your answer might get down votes too

Comment: GoDaddy and all ISP's are similar, just a suggestion. GoDaddy offers an ala cart menu, and lots of hand holding. It's probable that other ISP's do as well. I use 2 different ISP's at the moment. With a 'beginner' style question, GoDaddy came to mind as very user friendly. The question made sense to me, and I'm not too concerned about how people vote. Thanks.